# Error Setting up NPM start as service on Centos 8 -Failed to start My Project

Tags: angular, centos

I am trying to setup my Angular project as a service and setup "npm start" as a service

service.agent file

```
[Unit]
Description=My Project
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Environment=NODE_PORT=3000
Type=simple
User=www-data
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/root/agent
ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Run both command below no error

```
systemctl enable agent.service
systemctl start agent.service
```

Run the below and error appears
sudo journalctl -xfu agent

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

-- Automatic restarting of the unit agent.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Feb 25 14:48:09 v12623.securev.net systemd[1]: Stopped My Project.
-- Subject: Unit agent.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit agent.service has finished shutting down.
Feb 25 14:48:09 v12623.securev.net systemd[1]: agent.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 25 14:48:09 v12623.securev.net systemd[1]: agent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- The unit agent.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 25 14:48:09 v12623.securev.net systemd[1]: Failed to start My Project.
-- Subject: Unit agent.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit agent.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
```

Q1) Anything wrong with the configuration above?
Q2) Anyway to see the details why the service error?